# How to write a query using two tables and auxiliary table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table:

table1:

```
CREATE TABLE product(
product_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR (30),
price DECIMAL(20),
PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

table2:

```
CREATE TABLE people(
people_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
adress_id INT,
name VARCHAR (20),
lastName VARCHAR (20),
email VARCHAR (50),
PRIMARY KEY (people_id ),
);
```

auxiliary table:

```
CREATE TABLE buy (
people_id INT,
product_id int,
productAmount INT,
PRIMARY KEY (people_id , product_id)
);
```

I have to write a query:

Select all people who have NOT to buy any products.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: DECIMAL(20)? Remind me not to shop in your store!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM people
LEFT JOIN buy ON people.people_id = buy.people_id
WHERE buy.people_id IS NULL
GROUP BY people.people_id
```

Cheers

Comment: Technically, this looks correct, at a glance; however, I am also going to be picky and suggest you and OP to specify specific columns from said table aliases.   As is, you are going to return EVERYTHING from both tables where buy.people_ID is null. People.Name, People.LastName would suffice for this request.

Comment: Yes - if just first and lastname were required you could drop the all function and select the required columns only.

`SELECT people.name, people.lastName FROM people
LEFT JOIN buy ON people.people_id = buy.people_id
WHERE buy.people_id IS NULL
GROUP BY people.people_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Select * From People Where people_id not in (Select people_id from buy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

select * from people where people_id not in (select distinct people_id from buy);

Answer (score 0):

Any Query.

```
select * from people a
where not exists (
  select 1 from buy x where x.people_id = a.people_id
)
```